# uwp conditional xaml giving property not found error

Tags: xaml, uwp, fluent-design

I am creating a uwp app using **windows template studio** and using **hamburger menu** originally made by **uwp community toolkit**. And I want to add some fluent design features to my app. because my min version is creators update which lacks fluent design features so I wanna add these features with **conditional xaml**

min target : creators update
target : fall creators update

**code**

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu
    x:Name="NavigationMenu"
    IsAcrylicBrushPresent:PaneBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush}"
......
```

i also have added the following namespace in the page.

> xmlns:IsAcrylicBrushPresent="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsTypePresent(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush)"

**ERROR**

> The property "PaneBackground" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" is for the native controls, not for the UWP Community Toolkit controls!

You should use the same namespace you currently have for `controls` and just add the `?IsTypePresent(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush)` query bit.

It should look something like this:

```
xmlns:IsAcrylicBrushPresent="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls?IsTypePresent(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush)"
```